# DataTable comma

Tags: javascript, datatable

[image]
[image]
I using https://cdn.datatables.net . I'm downloading excel in my web site.While the real price should be 100,00, it is 10,000 in excel.Second picture is the right one. comma shifts a number in excel.How can I fix it ?
Sorry for my English

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment(lang == "en" ? 'DD/MM/YYYY' : 'DD.MM.YYYY');
    categories_table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
        order: [[1, 'desc']],
        language: datatable_lang,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                autoClose: 'true',
                text: '<i class="download icon">',
                tag: 'span',
                buttons: ['csv', 'print', 'excel']
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide some code so others can reproduce this problem. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I add my code @Mushroomator

Comment: Show sample data. Do you keep your prices as floats or as strings? If as string,s then it can be issue with formatting

Comment: I send picture @Justinas